Can the Telegram Business Bot read messages from 1-1 chats between users (not between users and Bot) and Group chats?
In this Telegram document, it says that the Telegram Business Bot can capture all updates of the channels it can access. From my understanding, the Bot API can capture messages from 1-1 and Group chat. After upgrading my account to Telegram Business, I created a Bot, enabled Business mode, granted all permissions to that Bot, and add that Bot to all 1-1 chats and several group chats. Then I used the below code to check if messages in 1-1 an Group chats can be captured by Bot or not. It does NOT work as I expected.
Please help educate me if that capability is feasible. In case it is feasible, how to implement that?
Thank you.
import requests
import time
import os

# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the token you got from BotFather
TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')
URL = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/"

def get_updates(offset=None):
    params = {'timeout': 100, 'offset': offset}
    response = requests.get(URL + 'getUpdates', params)
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            result_json = response.json()['result']
            return result_json
        except KeyError:
            print("The 'result' key was not found in the response. Here's the full response:")
            print(response.json())
            return []
    else:
        print(f"Failed to get updates. Status code: {response.status_code}. Response content: {response.text}")
        return []


def last_update(data):
    if len(data) > 0:
        last_update = data[-1]
    else:
        last_update = None
    return last_update

def main():
    last_update_id = None
    while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id)
        if updates:
            last_update_id = updates[-1]['update_id'] + 1
            print(updates[-1])  # Process the update here
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I tried the below code and expect messages in 1-1 chats can be captured but cannot.
